# slick db.run is not called

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I want to insert a record in database but the db.run is not called

my code looks like this

```
val insertQueryStep = processStepTemplates returning processStepTemplates.map(_.id) into ((processStep, id) => processStep.copy(id = Some(id)))


  /**
    * Generates a new ProcessStepTemplate
    *
    * @param step
    * @return
    */
  def addProcessStepTemplateToProcessTemplate(step: ProcessStepTemplatesModel, processId: Int): Future[Some[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]] = {
    println("In DTO: " + step + ", processtemplate: " + processId)

    //val p = processStepTemplates returning processStepTemplates.map(_.id) += step
    val p = insertQueryStep += step

    db.run(p).map(id => {
      println("Die Query lautet: " + p)
      println("Die erzeugte ID lautet: " + id)

      //Update the foreign key
      val q = for { p <- processStepTemplates if p.id == id } yield p.processtemplate
      val updateAction = q.update(Some(processId))

      db.run(updateAction).map(id => {
        println("Der neue Prozesschritt lautet: " + step)
        Some(step)
      })
      Some(step)
    })
  }
```

What could be a problem in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compose your futures as monads (with flatMap). Because the inner future will not complete.
Try to change your code in the following way (see comments #1, #2):

```
def addProcessStepTemplateToProcessTemplate(step: ProcessStepTemplatesModel, processId: Int): Future[Some[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]] = {
    println("In DTO: " + step + ", processtemplate: " + processId)

    //val p = processStepTemplates returning processStepTemplates.map(_.id) += step
    val p = insertQueryStep += step

    db.run(p).flatMap(id => {                   // #1 change map to flatMap
      println("Die Query lautet: " + p)
      println("Die erzeugte ID lautet: " + id)

      //Update the foreign key
      val q = for { p <- processStepTemplates if p.id == id } yield p.processtemplate
      val updateAction = q.update(Some(processId))

      val innerFuture = db.run(updateAction).map(id => {
        println("Der neue Prozesschritt lautet: " + step)
        Some(step)
      })
      innerFuture                              // # 2 return inner future
    })
  }
```

Also use a logging for detecting another issues (connected with db-schema, queries, etc).